# Are Ruby imported methods always private?

Tags: ruby, visibility, require, public, access-specifier

This is best explained with an example:

file1.rb:

```
def foo
  puts 123
end
```

file2.rb:

```
class A
  require 'file1'
end
A.new.foo
```

will give an error "': private method 'foo' called".

I can get around this by doing `A.new.send("foo")` but is there a way to make the imported methods public?

Edit: To clarify, I am not confusing include and require. Also, the reason why I cannot use normal inclusion (as many have rightly pointed out) is that this is part of a meta-programming setup. I need to allow the user to add functionality at run-time; eg he can say "run-this-app --include file1.rb" and the app will behave differently based on the code he wrote in file1.rb. Sorry should have explained clearer.

Edit: After reading Jorg's answer I realized my code does not behave exactly as intended, and he answers my (misguided) question perfectly. I am trying to do something more akin to `str=(entire file1.rb as string); A.class_exec(str)`.

Comment: Did you try `A.new.instance_eval{foo}`? It does not work for me (ruby 1.9.2).

Comment: Are you confusing `require with `include`?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Unfortunately not. I am looking for a cheap way to extend the program dynamically. The whole app is quite complicated but basically the string "file1.rb" is from user input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Global procedures in Ruby aren't *really* global procedures. They are methods, like everything else. In particular, when you define what *looks like* a global procedure, you are *actually* defining a private instance method of `Object`. Since every piece of code in Ruby is evaluated in the context of an object, this allows you to use those methods as if they were global procedures, since `self` is the default receiver, and `self` is an object whose class inherits from `Object`.

So, this:

```
# file1.rb

def foo
  puts 123
end
```

is actually equivalent to

```
# file1.rb

class Object
  private

  def foo
    puts 123
  end
end
```

Now you have a "global procedure" called `foo`, which you can call just like this:

```
foo
```

The *reason* why you can call it like this, is that this call is actually equivalent to

```
self.foo
```

and `self` is an object that includes `Object` in its ancestry chain, thus it inherits the private `foo` method.

[Note: to be precise, private methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver, *even if* that explicit receiver is `self`. So, to be really pedantic, it is *actually* equivalent to `self.send(:foo)` and not `self.foo`.]

The `A.new.foo` in your `file2.rb` is a red herring: you could just as well try `Object.new.foo` or `[].foo` or `42.foo` and get the same result.

By the way: `puts` and `require` are themselves examples of such "global procedures", which are actually private methods on `Object` (or more precisely, they are private methods on `Kernel` which is mixed into `Object`).

On a sidenote: it is *really* bad style to put calls to `require` inside a class definition, because it makes it look like the `require`d code is somehow scoped or namespaced inside the class, which is of course false. `require` simply runs the code in the file, nothing more.

So, while

```
# file2.rb

class A
  require 'file1.rb'
end
```

is perfectly valid code, it is also very confusing. It is much better to use the following, semantically equivalent, code:

```
# file2.rb

require 'file1.rb'

class A
end
```

That way it is perfectly clear to the reader of the code that `file1.rb` is in no way scoped or namespaced inside `A`.

Also, it is generally preferred to leave off the file extension, i.e. to use `require 'file1'` instead of `require 'file1.rb'`. This allows you to replace the Ruby file with, for example, native code (for MRI, YARV, Rubinius, MacRuby or JRuby), JVM byte code in a `.jar` or `.class` file (for JRuby), CIL byte code in `.dll` file (for IronRuby) and so on, without having to change any of your `require` calls.

One last comment: the idiomatic way to circumvent access protection is to use `send`, not `instance_eval`, i.e. use `A.new.send(:foo)` instead of `A.new.instance_eval {foo}`.

Comment: Thank you! This answer is really complete and clears up the misunderstandings I had --- that require was like C include that copy-pasted text. Is there a way to add the contents of file1.rb as methods of class A dynamically? Both the contents and location of file1 is only known at run-time and the user does not know about A. Or can I find the list of methods or modules defined in a file?

Answer (score 10):

This is a bad way to do this in Ruby. Try using mixins via modules instead:

file1.rb:

```
module IncludesFoo
  def foo
    puts 123
  end
end
```

file2.rb:

```
require 'file1.rb'

class A
  include IncludesFoo
end

A.new.foo
# => 123
```

Comment: Both 'file1.rb' and its contents come from user input and are loaded dynamically. Basically the user can enter a path at run-time, and the app will load the appropriate ruby file which will alter existing functionality, without restart, etc.

Sorry should have made this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

What about `load("file1", A)`? ([RDoc link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-load))